# Limit Django UpdateView to author

Tags: django, django-views

I've got a UpdateView in Django that I need to restrict to only the author. I having trouble grabbing the Author off of the request.

```
class MyPermissionMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_test_result = self.get_test_func()()
        if request.user != ????.user:                 #How do I grab the user('Author')??
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Autor instance user through `self.get_object()`

```
class MyPermissionMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user != self.get_object().author:         
                return HttpResponseForbidden()

             return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```